# tapestry. exists a dateTimeField?

Tags: java, datetime, datetimepicker, tapestry, datefield

I'm newb in tapestry but I'm afraid there is no datetimeField object.

If I use t:datefield component, I'll have a calendar to pick a date, but I would like to pick as well the time

I'm using tapestry 5.1.0.5 and I would like to use a component like GTimePicker http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/components/dojo/gtimepicker.html or http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/components/dojo/dropdowntimepicker.html

but this components looks that are only available for tapestry 4.1

I also tried with chenillekit but version 1.0.2 isn't available to download from maven repository and 1.3.3 is not compatible with my tapestry version

Thanks a lot in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

[tapx](https://github.com/hlship/tapx) includes a datefield with time option.

Answer (score 0):

the chenillekit components are outdated for current tapestry releases. i copied the sources from the chenillekit source repo and copied them to my project. there are currently no compile time issues, so you can use them without changes.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [date time field for Tapestry](http://www.chenillekit.org/chenillekit-tapestry/ref/org/chenillekit/tapestry/core/components/DateTimeField.html) from Chenillekit. Here's [the demo](http://www.chenillekit.org/demo/tapcomp/datetimefielddemo).

Comment: I tried with 1.0.2 but I wasn't able to use it (as I explained editing my question)